# Cisco 2811 debug command

Tags: cisco, debugging

Is there a command that allows the debugs to be shown in color. It would be easier for my techs to read the debug outputs. Didn't see any that I could find.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As Radius already wrote, there is no embedded function in IOS to colorize the debug output.

I nice way is to send the debug to a syslog or use a terminal client which supports logging to save into a textfile.
Then use a texteditor with language highlighting for example [notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm)
unfortunately there is no predefined language for cisco config but it's easy to configure your own highlighting as you may want it.

notepad++ supports to automatic refresh files while they are updated from another application in the background, so you see the output like in realtime.

Answer (score 0):

You may find some tools to do that but nothing on the Cisco router itself.